# Django session for multiple users

Tags: django

I have set `request.session['username']=username`

if two users are logged in simultaneously then will the request.session['username'] will be overwritten by the  username of the user who last logged in?

Comment: No it will not be because `request.session` refers difference sessions.

Answer (score 0):

As @falsetru said it won't

> When a page is requested, Django creates an HttpRequest object that contains metadata about the request.

For example if your app get 10 requests at the same time then 10 request objects will be created and these requests are different from each other. `session` is an attribute on request object.